# How to access a webtable element using xpath if the webtable element is inside a td tag

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to access the webtable elements inside the table2 , please see the page source below :

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr class="head">
        <td class="left" colspan="2">
            <!--PAGE LINKS-->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left_link">
            <h1>
                <a name="nav_home" href="index.html" id="home_link" class="home">HOME</a><br>
                <a name="nav_adopt" href="adoption.html" id="adoption_link">ADOPTION</a><br>
                <a name="nav_about" href="about.html" id="about_link">ABOUT</a><br>
                <a name="nav_contact" href="contact.html" id="contact_link">CONTACT</a><br>
            </h1>
        </td>
        <td class="content">
            <h1>
                CONTACT US
            </h1>
            <hr>
            <p>
                Use the form below to contact us if you have any questions, queries or even any requests.
                We are always happy to hear from you all.
            </p>
            <h1 class="subhead">Contact Form</h1>
            <form name="message_form">
                <table id="table2" class="inner_table">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Enter Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="name_field"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                        <input type="radio" id="rinfo" name="rbutton" value="information">Information
                        <input type="radio" id="rdona" name="rbutton" value="Donation">Donation
                        <input type="radio" id="radop" name="rbutton" value="Donation">Adoption
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

For example i am not able to access the name inside the table2.

I tried accessing using below but failed .

driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='table1']/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table[@class='inner_table']/tr[1]/td[1))

Comment: `table2` has an id of `table2` so why not use that directly

Answer (score 2):

Try this below `xpath`

```
//table[@id='table2']/..//following::input[@name='name_field']
```

**Explanation of xpath:-** Use `id` attribute of `<table>` tag and move ahead with `<input>` tag using `following` keyword.

This above `xpath` will locate the Enter Name field text box.

**Note:-** Instead of using `absolute xpath`, Use `relative xpath`.

Comment: Have you this answer?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use xpath on selenium, since elements might tend to change and you have to refactor your selector if you add another element.

To answer your question, you can use the id for `table2` and select the desired element.

Comment: I tried using below code but the size is returning as 0 instead of 2

 
 int table = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='inner_table']/tr[1]/td")).size();
  
  System.out.println("Table Size is " + table);

Comment: Also can you advise what would be the most optimal way to handle this scenario.

Comment: @Vish hi -  I would advise using something like this as well `By.cssSelector("inner_table > tr:nth-child(1)")`

Or once you get the elements from the table using `By.id("table2")` you can just pick the first element

Answer (score 0):

Try xpath like below:

to access input filed with name 'name_field' use below xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='table2' and @class= 'inner_table']//input[@type='text' and @name='name_field']")
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a CSS selector as simple as `input[name='name_field']` or if that isn't specific enough, use `#table2 input[name='name_field']`.

Answer (score 0):

In web tables, you can use xPath to reach parent of an element and then finding the `preceding-sibling` or the `following-sibling` of td tags

This tutorial will help you:
http://www.seleniumtests.com/2011/10/using-xpath-to-reach-parent-of-element.html